Upgraded .Net 4.8 to .Net8.0 (Core), Microsoft.Office.Interop no longer recognises certain key words
I've upgraded a legacy C# WPF app from .Net 4.8 to .Net8.0 (Core).
Removed the NuGet packages for Microsoft.Office.Interop both word and excel and replaced with COM references (8.7 and 1.9 respectively).
This is using the same version of office as before the .Net upgrade.
The issue is it no longer recognises certain key words:
Am I missing something obvious or have Microsoft introduced some breaking changes?
Thanks


This shows the classes are missing, possibly because the correct references are missing or not loaded at all. You migrated from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET Core 8, a completely different, cross-platform runtime and SDK. COM is a Windows-only feature, so your application needs to target net8.0-windows, not the cross-platform net8.0. You won't be able to use .NET Framework interop libraries either. .NET Core projects can load .NEt Core or .NET Standard libraries only.

Check the COM Interop documentation. You may not have to do any manual work though. Visual Studio's Add COM Reference should be able to add a reference to the Word  type library

You should be able to use the .NET 8 NuGet packages rather than the COM references. Why did you decide to use COM?

Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos now solved.
